# Audio streaming with Android MediaPlayer does' support for gingerbread(Android 2.3)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Android `MediaPlayer` streaming audio doesn't support for the `gingerbread(Android 2.3)` os `version`.

This sample code works fine with `android 4.0(ICS)` version. but this same sample doesn't support `Android 2.3`.

```
MediaPlayer radioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
radioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);                              
radioPlayer.setDataSource("http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138");  // set Sample url

radioPlayer.prepareAsync();                 
radioPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Guess this doesn't make much difference but you should not call ``prepareAsync`` and ``start`` next to each other.

Comment: No I couldn't fix the problem yet.

Comment: UP ! Did you solve your problem ? I got the same atm

Answer (score 0):

**Android mediaplayer supports audio streaming in gingerbread.**

You didn't check the reason behind not playing.

> I suggest you to implement **onErrorListener** and **onPreparedListener**. and call `mediaplayer.start();` inside **onPrepare**.

```
public void initMusicPlayer(){
        //set player properties
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        //set listeners
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }
```

**Note.**

if your stream starts with https replace it with http for gingerbread.

And may be this format is not supported in gingerbread. Have a [**look at this.**](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)